# Topology of a hypersurface complement

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-topology

Is there a relatively explicit way to describe the topology of $\mathbb{CP}^{3}\setminus D$ where $D$ is a smooth, degree 4 hypersurface?

Comment: What counts as explicit for you?

Comment: I don't know exactly, a handle decomposition for example, or a compact space which it deformation retracts onto.

Comment: I wouldn't know any references or a direct statement. This is what I would try: You can compute all kinds of topological information of $D$, for example its homology. Then the mayer-vietoris sequence relates the homology of $CP^3$, $D$ and the complement you are after.